# QlikView - Struggling to produce Bubble / scatter from record-data

Tags: qlikview

I would like to make a Bubble-scatter where the data looks like:

Each row is an 'event', with a Day of the event and the event's grade

```
Day  | Grade
------------
 1   |  A
 1   |  A
 1   |  B
 1   | (empty)
 1   |  B
 2   |  A
```

I want this to turn into a bubble graph that looks like :

Day along the X-axis ( 1, 2)

On Y-axis I would like to see A,B (vertically)

And I would expect

- one big bubble for day-1 A
- one big bubble for day-2 A
- one little bubble for day-2 A

Given the data above

It is either refusing to display anything at all saying 'undefined values'

I'm really struggling to understand how this bubble/scatter works, and the documentation isn't helping

It asks for Dimension, Measure, Measure and I am putting in many variations of Day, Count(Grade) and Avg(Grade)

Answer (score 0):

Bubble charts are a bit tricky.
In your case you need 2 dimensions: dimension 1 (Grade) and dimension 2 (Day). 
Expression is as simple as `sum(1)` (take into account that you are already double-filtering the data because you have 2 dimensions). To avoid extra bubbles due to the Null entries, just select "ignore null values" in the dimension panel options.